# Microsoft true type fonts on mac

Tags: ms-office, font, latex

How do I install the mainstream Microsoft Hebrew true-type fonts (David, Arial, Times New Roman Hebrew) in Mac? I would like to use these fonts both in MS-Office and Latex documents.

In the Linux\Debian world there is a package called [msttcorefonts](http://packages.debian.org/stable/x11/msttcorefonts), that fetches these fonts from the Microsoft site. I'm not sure where I can download these fonts, is it legal to use them in Mac, and whether there are copyright issues with documents created with them.

Comment: MS Word for Mac has never supported RTL scripts.  Instead you need to use Mellel (the best), or Text Edit, Nisus Writer, or OpenOffice.

Answer (score 1):

Applications -> Font Book.

This controls fonts in OSX.

You can enable/disable, validate and check them, create custom groupings, etc.

From within Font Book you can open up new fonts: File -> Add Fonts, or just drag them into it. Even just double-clicking the font itself should prompt you to install it.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some data to my question - I want to know where can I get these fonts, and is it legal to use them.

Comment: If they're MS fonts, and you own MS Office Hebrew edition, which I would think comes with them, you should be fine. Otherwise you can purchase fonts from any foundry or designer to use, depending on licensing. For MS specifics, this will answer some questions: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/hebrew-font/38815df6-0fa1-49f7-8a7a-5b250a2fcd50

Comment: and this: http://www.dougshivers.com/mikhtav/osx.html